# How to make an inbuilt webcam work

Tags: 18.04, drivers, usb, webcam, cheese

This question arises in a lot of variants and so I got a lot of hints how I could solve my issue - but until now nothing really worked for me.

At first I tried to use *cheese* as supposed in various posts. But instead of a picture is appearing cheese only says **No device found**.

Then I used *camorama* and here I received this message

[image]

And now I followed this ["tutorial"](http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Set_up_a_Webcam_with_Linux) and because the path **/dev/video0** is missing. Finally I have to follow the instructions under the section *Troubleshooting*

- I have to use `hwinfo --usb` to find my webcam and the needed *Driver Activation Cmd* line to continue the process
- But with `hwinfo --usb` or `hwinfo --pci` or `sudo lshw|fgrep -i cam`
- or simply `lsusb` or `lspci -vv`

I couldn't find anything proper - in my opinion. I mention this explicitly because I'm still new to ubuntu.

Okay that's my research until now... do you have some hints how I can solve this issue? Many thanks in advance!

**Note**: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 bionic and my laptop is an *HP Z Book 15 G3* with an inbuilt *Webcam: 720 p HD Webcam*

**Additional note**:

[image]

[image]

When I enter `sudo hwinfo --usb` I get the following image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add yourself to the group that `/dev/video0` belongs too.

The group will be `video` so do a

```
sudo usermod -a -G video $USER
```

The command `groups` should show you have `video` added to your groups.

That will give you access to the device.

Comment: Can you please name the steps I have to take? I just entered in the terminal the `sudo usermod -a -G video $USER` command and nothing changed... for USER I tried also my name...

Comment: Relog your user in.

Comment: @nobody: Okay, after relogging I'm in the group `video` but still it doesn't work. I have also verified if `/dev/video0` exits - it's still missing. How can I create this path proper?

Comment: check for `/dev/video*` It might not be 0 on your system :)

Comment: Please see my *additional note* in my question. There isn't existing a *video** folder. This tells also the terminal *file or directory not found* when entering `/dev/video*`

Comment: `/dev/video*`is not a folder. And I said to "check" so list it commandline with `ls -ltr /dev/video*` not to -execute- `/dev/video*` These devices will be near the end of the image you posted not at the beginning

Comment: Did you try `sudo rmmod uvcvideo` followed by `sudo modprobe uvcvideo` ?

Comment: This link tells that probes once failed for your laptop and manual reconfiguration is needed. https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:04f2-b51c&page=1#status

Comment: Thanks for your patience - but it still remains the same. *file or directory not found*. See another image in my question.

Comment: @tueftla The hwinfo --usb command must be used with superuser rights, like : `sudo hwinfo --usb`.

Comment: @starkus: `sudo rmmod uvcvideo` tells *rmmod: ERROR: Module uvcvideo is not currently loaded* and `sudo modprobe uvcvideo` has done nothing in my opinion... and what should I notice with `sudo hwinfo --usb`? I have done it, but couldn't find the ID (a482d75fd1) mentioned in your proposed link. See the image above...

Comment: The cam needs the uvc driver loaded to work properly. Not sure what you'd need to do if it's badly supported. I would give replacing the `uvc_driver.c` with the mentioned version from `https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/media/usb/uvc/uvc_driver.c` a try. But I'm not sure if this would work and not sure if you would need to recompile the kernel. Sorry.

Comment: @starkus: Thanks for your commenting and for further hints - I appreciate that and perhaps I will solve this issue...

Comment: @tueftla Did you find any workaround to this?

Comment: @starkus: Until now not... I will search and when I find a solution I will post it here.